# Why Font-Awesome icon class is different

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

Why fontawesome icon class is different

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
<i class="fas fa-pencil"></i>
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
```

Comment: Is there any way to easily copy the tag without having to open the icon?  I know you can see the fa-icon name by hovering or with the "cheat sheet"...but is there any way to know whether the icon is fas / fab / far etc. without navigating to the icon page?

Comment: @dcclassics yes there is a way. `fab` is for brands, so it's easy to recognize all icons. `fas` - solid icons are usually filled with transparent outlines. `far` regular and `fal` light are similar. These icons are different than `fas` solid because they are mostly outlines and differ only in outline width. `fal` light icons have thinner outline compared to `far` regular.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands.

Please Refer to this

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use
[image]

Answer (score 18):

Chek out Font Awesome DOCS:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

This image has all the informations about prefixes so there is really nothing more to add :)

Font Awesome 5.10.0+ has duotone icons with new prefix `fad`.

[image]

Comment: Although this page says `fa` should still work where `fas` also now does: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#changes

Answer (score 0):

I will give answer according to your code only.
Font awesome is an amazing easy to use icon library.

- The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands.
- 'fa' alone means font awesome. It is no longer used. But I use it with previous link I have my earlier web creations and it works fine.
- fas: font awesome solid. It is also free to use.
- fab: font awesome brands. Free to use

Rest of the styles everyone above is talking about are: **regular** (`far`), **light** (`fal`) and **duotone** (`fad`) are all pro versions. They are paid.

Further information can be found on: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

I hope I have explained with details.

Answer (score 0):

#### FONT AWESOME 6

In Font Awesome 6 you have new styles and new classes:

More details: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/whats-changed#full-style-names

[image]