# Font Awesome icons no longer showing on page

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am working on a site, and just recently, the social media icons are no longer appearing on the site, they are just boxes. The site in question is [sccds.org](https://sccds.org/).

They were working a couple days ago, and nothing was updated (It's a wordpress site) when they just suddenly stopped showing up. The link used to serve the css is the same as it used to be, the icons are the same with the same classes, the plugin used to display the icons is the same, everything is the same, but for some reason, the icons themselves will no longer display.

There are no errors in the console and nothing is failing to load, so I am at a loss as to how the icons can just suddenly no longer show up. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: you update something? the plugin, wordpress ?

Comment: Nope, it happened over the weekend, no one did anything to the site and nothing was updated.

Comment: Can you check this out? https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11946 I tried changing the `font-family` to `fontawesome` and the icon shows. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyjmf.jpg

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913487/924299) , the "fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5". The icons seem to work with the `fab` prefix.

Comment: I've just taken a look at the link you provided in your querstion @EricBrown and the social media icons on the top nav bar are displaying in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @ManojKumar That did it, changing the font family brought them back. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is your styles. Some of the icons require a particular font-weight. Recently, I added a rule to my stylesheets which broke several icons I was using (and they were being rendered as boxes).

```
.fas, .far, .fab { font-weight: normal; }
```

Once I removed that from my css, the icons showed up properly.