# New Font Awesome icon not showing even though it exists in theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've got a weird problem that I can't figure out. In my WordPress installation I've got a Font Awesome icon that shows up at the top. It's `fa-shopping-basket` or `f291`. I think that is from Font Awesome Version 5. I'm also trying to add that same shopping basket icon to the Add to Cart button. So what I've done is add the following to my custom CSS:

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button:after {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    float:none;
    content: "\f291";
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

But strangely enough, even though this icon is being called properly by the theme (as it's obviously showing at the top of the page), when I call `f291` with the above CSS, I get a different, seemingly older version. You can see this in the pic below.

[image]

The theme is obviously recognizing `f291` as this new icon, but I get this different older version in the button though. I've tried stuff like `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"` and `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"` but I just get that square placeholder. How can I get around this?

Comment: Not sure, but I think Font Awesome 5 uses `fas` instead of `fa` as the class prefix. [why-font-awesome-icon-class-is-different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913423/why-font-awesome-icon-class-is-different)

Comment: @AndrewHalpern Okay, thanks. But I'm not sure how I'd actually call that for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've figured it out. It was Elementor that was using Font Awesome 5 but the actual WordPress pages were using 4. I added FA v5 to the actual WordPress installation itself and that sorted it out.